# Jmeter - How to do parallel request

Tags: jmeter

I have a web Service request that push a notification in a screen,I want to measure the time taken to display the notification in the screen after the request of the web service requested,so I  want to send both requests in parallel. How can i do that ?

[![I want the two highlighted steps to be done concurrently ][1]][1]

The two highlighted steps not occurred concurrently.

Comment: Actually i dont know how to design it in Jmeter that is why am asking about it

Answer (score 5):

JMeter provides [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) which allows grouping requests so they could be executed at exactly in the same moment. Just add a Synchronizing Timer to your test plan and make sure that

- it is at the same level with both requests
- number of virtual users in [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) is >= what is set in the Synchronizing Timer

[image: Synchronizing Timer Example]

See [Using the JMeter Synchronizing Timer](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) for more information on running specific requests at the same time in your JMeter test.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for your reply :)

Comment: so lets say my controller has 100 requests in it (sequenced) with the addition of the sync-timer, all of them will be sort of queued and released at once so I can hit my website with 100 concurrent requests ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md) that you can install with [jmeter-plugins manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/install/Install/)

You use Parallel Controller:

[image: Parallel Controller]

Comment: so if I want to send 1000 requests in parallel do I have to add 1000 controllers?